# Troubles with installation CKEditor on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

Greetings good people,

I decided to install CKEditor on Drupal 7.43, the following steps -

1. Set the module CKEditor from here - https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor
2. The site, http://ckeditor.com/, chosen Add-ons, select the version full editor, and then chose the additions are needed. Then download.
3. Copy the downloaded folder in CKEditor - \ sites \ all \ modules \ ckeditor \ ckeditor \
4. Then he turned on the CKEditor.

The problem is this -
Now edit the articles following problem - CKEditor panels displayed on the screen, but all gray, inactive, do not work on pressing the button does not respond. Change and create a "Text Formats" tried, without effect. Settings CKEditor Global profile -% m / ckeditor

Please help to solve this problem.

2016-04-04
So the problem is solved.
that's how it was:

1. In the bottom of the page load CKEditor has two checkboxes Optimized and Source (Big N'Slow). We must choose the Source (Big N'Slow)
2. Now for the problem of inactive buttons. There Addon CSS Animations for CKEditor, this addon blocked the normal execution of the program.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check user's permissions to use Text format

Answer (score 0):

There are some additional configuration that needs to be set. See the [Quick Start Guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_for_Drupal/Open_Source/Drupal_7/Quick_Start) for the steps to take.

Comment: Maybe something I do not understand .
So when I download CKEditor assembly of the site, it does not have all the necessary adjustments ? And even if so , then why offer to add plug-ins to the editor that will not work . Or why they offer me to download the editor and place it in the folder / CKEditor / CKEditor /.?